Preline component library JavaScript not working when used in browser via CDN
I am having problems with what should be a very simple task. I would like to use Preline's Tailwind CSS component library. To be exact, I would like to use this basic modal sample found in the documentation:
<button type="button" class="py-3 px-4 inline-flex items-center gap-x-2 text-sm font-medium rounded-lg border border-transparent bg-blue-600 text-white hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none focus:bg-blue-700 disabled:opacity-50 disabled:pointer-events-none" aria-haspopup="dialog" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="hs-basic-modal" data-hs-overlay="#hs-basic-modal">
  Open modal
</button>

<div id="hs-basic-modal" class="hs-overlay hs-overlay-open:opacity-100 hs-overlay-open:duration-500 hidden size-full fixed top-0 start-0 z-[80] opacity-0 overflow-x-hidden transition-all overflow-y-auto pointer-events-none" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="hs-basic-modal-label">
  <div class="sm:max-w-lg sm:w-full m-3 sm:mx-auto">
    <div class="flex flex-col bg-white border shadow-sm rounded-xl pointer-events-auto">
      <div class="flex justify-between items-center py-3 px-4 border-b">
        <h3 id="hs-basic-modal-label" class="font-bold text-gray-800">
          Modal title
        </h3>
        <button type="button" class="size-8 inline-flex justify-center items-center gap-x-2 rounded-full border border-transparent bg-gray-100 text-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-200 disabled:opacity-50 disabled:pointer-events-none" aria-label="Close" data-hs-overlay="#hs-basic-modal">
          <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
          <svg class="shrink-0 size-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
            <path d="M18 6 6 18"></path>
            <path d="m6 6 12 12"></path>
          </svg>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="p-4 overflow-y-auto">
        <p class="mt-1 text-gray-800">
          This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-end items-center gap-x-2 py-3 px-4 border-t">
        <button type="button" class="py-2 px-3 inline-flex items-center gap-x-2 text-sm font-medium rounded-lg border border-gray-200 bg-white text-gray-800 shadow-sm hover:bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-50 disabled:opacity-50 disabled:pointer-events-none" data-hs-overlay="#hs-basic-modal">
          Close
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="py-2 px-3 inline-flex items-center gap-x-2 text-sm font-medium rounded-lg border border-transparent bg-blue-600 text-white hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none focus:bg-blue-700 disabled:opacity-50 disabled:pointer-events-none">
          Save changes
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

The tricky part is that this project does not use a Node JS server. This is why searched for its JavaScript library CDN and included it to my HTML file:
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/preline@2.4.1/dist/preline.min.js"></script>

However, when trying to test the modal window, the window just goes dark (as if there modal was opened) but nothing happens. I have tried with multiple browsers and even to upload the preline.min.js file to my server and link it locally but it does not work either. I have checked and the code of the CDN's preline.min.js file seems to be identical to what you when you install it via NPM. Other preline components seem to be partially working.
Screenshot of the problem
This is the full code of my HTML page:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Sample</title>

    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" class="py-3 px-4 inline-flex items-center gap-x-2 text-sm font-medium rounded-lg border border-transparent bg-blue-600 text-white hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none focus:bg-blue-700 disabled:opacity-50 disabled:pointer-events-none" aria-haspopup="dialog" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="hs-basic-modal" data-hs-overlay="#hs-basic-modal">
    Open modal
  </button>
  
  <div id="hs-basic-modal" class="hs-overlay hs-overlay-open:opacity-100 hs-overlay-open:duration-500 hidden size-full fixed top-0 start-0 z-[80] opacity-0 overflow-x-hidden transition-all overflow-y-auto pointer-events-none" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="hs-basic-modal-label">
    <div class="sm:max-w-lg sm:w-full m-3 sm:mx-auto">
      <div class="flex flex-col bg-white border shadow-sm rounded-xl pointer-events-auto">
        <div class="flex justify-between items-center py-3 px-4 border-b">
          <h3 id="hs-basic-modal-label" class="font-bold text-gray-800">
            Modal title
          </h3>
          <button type="button" class="size-8 inline-flex justify-center items-center gap-x-2 rounded-full border border-transparent bg-gray-100 text-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-200 disabled:opacity-50 disabled:pointer-events-none" aria-label="Close" data-hs-overlay="#hs-basic-modal">
            <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
            <svg class="shrink-0 size-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
              <path d="M18 6 6 18"></path>
              <path d="m6 6 12 12"></path>
            </svg>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="p-4 overflow-y-auto">
          <p class="mt-1 text-gray-800">
            This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="flex justify-end items-center gap-x-2 py-3 px-4 border-t">
          <button type="button" class="py-2 px-3 inline-flex items-center gap-x-2 text-sm font-medium rounded-lg border border-gray-200 bg-white text-gray-800 shadow-sm hover:bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-50 disabled:opacity-50 disabled:pointer-events-none" data-hs-overlay="#hs-basic-modal">
            Close
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="py-2 px-3 inline-flex items-center gap-x-2 text-sm font-medium rounded-lg border border-transparent bg-blue-600 text-white hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none focus:bg-blue-700 disabled:opacity-50 disabled:pointer-events-none">
            Save changes
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/preline@2.4.1/dist/preline.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

I would be very grateful for any suggestions to get this working.

similar

You are correct @James. Thank you for pointing that out. It is not possible to use Preline components via CDN without Node JS.
